# Interpretations of questions

Tags: discussion

How do we interpret a question correctly when there exits multiple intepretations? for example in this question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/321428/why-does-the-metric-remain-unchanged-in-special-relativity/321433#321433,)

i interpreted it one way and answered, but apparently some others(not the OP) downvoted it saying it dosen't have enough information. Can someone suggest ways to deal with such misunderstandings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All questions are a little bit ambiguous, and somewhat open to interpretation. But if a question admits significantly different interpretations, to the extent that a typical answerer might be confused about what they're really supposed to be answering, the best thing to do is flag it (or vote to put it on hold, if you have enough reputation) as "unclear what you're asking". That way we avoid having multiple conflicting and confusing answers until the asker is able to clarify the question. To go along with this, it helps to leave a comment pointing out how the question is unclear, or upvote a comment which gives that information if one already exists.

You can also downvote the question if you like. A lack of clarity that impedes people's ability to answer the question is one good use of a downvote. You may want to check back later to see if the question has been improved, and if so, remove your downvote.

Note that this applies whether you yourself see multiple confusing interpretations of the question, or some people only see one interpretation and others see a drastically different one. The remedy is the same either way.

Comment: Perhaps OP is referring to the situation where somebody interprets a question one way (and doesn't see the other possible interpretations) rather than picking one of many and going with it. That's a more subtle case -- in the mind of the answerer, it is crystal clear and not worthy of downvote/closing. Until somebody else comes along and points out the different interpretation.

Comment: And somewhat ironically, that could be exactly what has happened with this Q&A since you interpreted the question one way, and I, another. ;) The original question is rather unclear!

Comment: Well, I think I understood that, but I should clarify my answer to indicate that I'm talking about the case where you've realized that the question is unclear, whether because you see multiple interpretations yourself or because someone else has pointed out a different interpretation that you didn't notice at first. That being said, all questions are a _little_ bit ambiguous. We don't want to go so far as requiring that a question be turned into some formal technical specification!

Answer (score 3):

The question you link is largely incomprehensible. I asked the OP for clarification, and since they haven't responded I have voted to close as unclear.

The downvotes on your answer are a little unkind, but they just indicate that a few people thought your answer was unhelpful so I wouldn't assign too much significance to them.

I have answered questions based on my guess about what the OP actually wants to know, but in those cases I normally start my answer by saying something like:

> I'm assuming you are asking about <insert guess here>. Ignore this answer if this is not the case.

So it is clear exactly what question my answer is addressing. I think your answer would benefit from some statement making it clear exactly what your answer is aimed at. At the moment it isn't clear to me what point you are making.

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted. If whoever downvoted would like to leave a comment I would be interested to know what they disagreed with.

Comment: I deleted a comment I'd made based on a partial understanding of a partial reading of the answer here. Not sure the downvote, but I'd agree with this for the most part ( I'd personally not answer based on the guess, but can't fault anyone for it)